# Python Password Checker - If statement not correct

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to generate a password checker in python that uses the following rules to determine the strength of a user's password.

The user's password is WEAK if it is less than 6 characters long.
The user's password is STRONG if it contains at least 13 characters, at least 1 lower case letter at least 1 capital letter and at least 1 numerical digit.
The user has a MEDIUM password if it is neither a strong or weak password.

I have generated the following code:

```
def strengthOfPassword ( pass ):
    strongness = 0
    up = 0
    low = 0
    num = 0
    for i in pass:
        if i.islower():
            low += 1
        if i.isupper():
            up += 1
        if i.isdigit():
            num +=1 
    print (len(pass))
    if len(pass) >= 13:
        if up > 0 and low > 0 and num > 0:
            strongness = "STRONG PASSWORD"
    if len(pass) < 6: 
        strongness = "WEAK PASSWORD"
    else:
        strongness = "MEDIUM PASSWORD"

    return strongness

strengthOfPassword("2Benji3all4Kiwi")
```

The code works for most test cases, however for the string "2Benji3all4Kiwi", the code incorrectly states that this is a medium password, rather than a strong password, despite meeting all of the criteria for a strong password. Why is this?

Comment: Fairly confident that this code doesn't even run

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: it fails because `len(pass) < 6` is False, so it moves to the `else` clause. change to `elif len(pass) < 6`. (it also doesn't run for me as `pass` is a keyword)

Comment: `pass` is a reserved word; you can't use that as a parameter name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To figure out why code is misbehaving, a **debugger** can be helpful. You can step through your code line by line while it is executed and see the value of your variables. Here you could observe that after setting `strongness` to `STRONG PASSWORD` the method does not yet return. Instead it continues. Two lines later `len(pass) < 6` evaluates to false, so it goes into the `else` and overwrites `strongness` with `MEDIUM PASSWORD`.

What you should do instead is return the strength as soon as you determine it.

Which brings me to a second improvable point: Early returns. It makes your code easier to read by reducing nesting (indentation-depth) and errors like this one, because you don't have to remember the decisions from the code above.

Another important one is that `pass` is a reserved keyword in Python. It's used for e.g. empty methods or conditions. So rename your variable to not use a reserved keyword.

```py
def strength_of_password(password):
    up = 0
    low = 0
    num = 0

    for i in password:
        if i.islower():
            low += 1
        elif i.isupper():
            up += 1
        elif i.isdigit():
            num +=1 

    if len(password) >= 13 and up > 0 and low > 0 and num > 0:
        return "STRONG PASSWORD"

    if len(password) < 6: 
        return "WEAK PASSWORD"

    return "MEDIUM PASSWORD"

print(strength_of_password("2Benji3all4Kiwi"))
```

Finally, there's a [style guide for Python, called PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which recommends using `snake_case` for method names (and much more) to increase readability and thus make it easier for other developers to understand existing code.

Comment: Great answer.. :p

Comment: I'll type faster next time xD

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows wrong because the if else structure overwrites your "STRONG PASSWORD". You can fix this by returning early in your function.

Also don't use 'pass' as variable or parameter as it is a reserverd keyword.

```
def strengthOfPassword(password):
    strongness = 0
    up = 0
    low = 0
    num = 0
    for i in password:
        if i.islower():
            low += 1
        if i.isupper():
            up += 1
        if i.isdigit():
            num +=1 
    if len(password) >= 13:
        if up > 0 and low > 0 and num > 0:
            # As this returns, it will not execute any other code
            return "STRONG PASSWORD"
    if len(passwo) < 6:
        return "WEAK PASSWORD"
    else:
        return "MEDIUM PASSWORD"

strengthOfPassword("2Benji3all4Kiwi")
```